# Using values in a column to designate/activate a specific row

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I currently have a code that finds the first empty cell in a specific column and saves the result of a "SumIfs" calculation into that cell.  It runs for multiple columns on multiple criteria.  The example below is one instance where I search for the criteria "R" and "ECHO", sum the corresponding values from column 16, and place the result in column "C" of another worksheet:

```
Sub SumIfs()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("previous_day_split")
Worksheets("daily_balance").Activate

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
Application.SumIfs(ws2.Columns(16), ws2.Columns(15), "R", ws2.Columns(20), "ECHO")

End Sub
```

It works great, but now instead of just placing the result in the first empty cell of column "C", I want to find a way to designate a row (not always going to be the first empty one) based on specific dates in the first column of "daily_balance".

In short, for example, I want the code to essentially search for a date (say 11/2/2015) in the first column of the worksheet "daily_balance", designate that row as the row to dump the values into, run the SumIfs function in "ws2", and place the results in column "C" for the row containing 11/2/2015.

Any suggestions or ideas on the best way to designate a row based on criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily look for a specific value in a column using `Do While` loop:

```
i = 0
Do While Cells(i, "A") <> {lookup_value} And Cells(i, "A") <> ""
    i = i + 1
loop

'Check that {i} holds row number for our lookup value and not for an empty one
if Cells(i, "A") = {lookup_value} then
    'Do your calculations here
    'And then use {i} as row number to save your result.
end if
```

So `{lookup_value}` is a constant or variable holding the date you are looking for. In case your dates are not well formated you might need to use `CDate()` to bring your lookup_value and cell value to the same format, meaning that instead of:

```
Do While Cells(i, "A") <> {lookup_value} And Cells(i, "A") <> ""
```

you should use:

```
Do While CDate(Cells(i, "A")) <> CDate({lookup_value}) And Cells(i, "A") <> ""
```

Good luck with that, and feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: great thanks, I'll give that a shot!  Just a thought--would it be possible to simply search for the date in column "A", count how many rows down that value is, then just set that count as a variable (i for instance) and use i later on when defining the location to return the SumIfs results? If so, how would you structure that in code?

Comment: @Willarci3 You would structure that in code exactly as I've done in your follow-on question. That is precisely what my answer does here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33488057/3566998

Comment: The advice I always give to anyone who starts with VBA - use Record Macro whenever you can. Of course you can search for the date, the only thing to take in account is that search function does not return you the row number of match, it just selects the cell with the match. So you will need to use ActiveCell.Row or something like that to refer to the row number. And if you just record macro, then search for the date in related column you can see exactly how it works.

Comment: I was going to let this go, but I can't. If this code is in a standard module, you really must qualify the Cells method... or you are asking for trouble. But each Cell method is inefficient and you are forcing it to be called twice for every cell in the range, since VBA does not short-circuit expression evaluation. You can most certainly get the row number of the date directly, as in my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33488057/3566998