# Search column for value and count number of rows

Tags: excel, vba, search, count

I have a large workbook that contains a list of dates in column "A" of Sheet1.  Is there a way to search the column for a specific date, count how many rows down it is, then set that number as a variable that I can use in a range in the next bit of VBA code?

Basically, I want to be able to find the row number associated with the date, then reference that row later on.

Comment: Have you tried `find`?

Comment: Would that allow me to count the number of rows down that the value is though? I'm more concerned with figuring out how to determine the number of rows, then using that number later on in the code.

Comment: Once you find it, you can get the row. Edit: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479575/vba-how-to-find-search-value-from-sheet-dmr-and-then-from-found-search-value/31480620#31480620)

Comment: Right, but any ideas on how to go about using code to determine the row number and remembering it?

Comment: If you read the link, you would see `fRow = f.Row` where `fRow` is a variable... Edit: Hero's answer below is more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
Dim MyDate&, TheRow&
MyDate = DateSerial(2015, 4, 11)
TheRow = Application.Match(MyDate, Sheet1.[a:a], 0)
```

Comment: Groovy but not working for me :/ Do I need special formatting?

Comment: So... whomever voted this down... get a grip. This perfectly answers OP's question.

Comment: He is hit an miss whether he will respond or not, looking into his history and the fact that he asked a question nearly identical and got an answer, leads me to believe he gets what he wants and moves on.  I am still waiting nearly a month on an answer I gave him.

Comment: Thanks for the intel, @ScottCraner.

Comment: @ScottCraner--new to both VBA and Stack Overflow, so no hard feelings... Have had a lot of other stuff on my plate at work, but will try and take a look at it today.. thanks

Comment: Alright @ExcelHero so basically by using the Match function, the code will locate the position of "MyDate", then save save it as "The Row" right? So would I then just use "The Row" later on as a part of my range for the SumIfs function?

Comment: @Willarci3 Yes, you would.

Comment: Great thanks.  I keep getting a 'Type Mismatch' error on the third row... In my spreadsheet, I've got the dates formatted as short dates, do I need to specify that in the code? Also just out of curiosity, what does the ampersand do when you're dimensioning the variables?

Comment: Third row? Nothing special needs to be done in the code. As long as the date you are searching for is in the COLUMN specified (column A in my example) it will find it. If the date is not in the column then you will get an error. That being said, the date in the column must be a true Excel date and not text. If you can change how it formats with the various date formats under number formatting, the it is a true Excel date. The ampersand is just shorthand for "As Long".